# MVC Entity Framework connection string doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When I google "MVC connection string" or something similar, I get a bunch of questions/articles about this, and all of those I have read says to edit a Web.config file. Is there any reasons for this not working in my project?

My project uses Entity Framework, and now it works on a local db. I have edited 2x Web.config files (one in the project folder, and another in the Views folder - I dont really know the difference). These files did not originally have any `<connectionStrings>` tags, so I added this manually, to both files:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=mysite.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Developer;User ID=user;Password=pass" providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/></connectionStrings>
```

.. but it still uses my localhost database. Is there any obvious thing Im missing??

EDIT:

Deleting debug and rebuilding did not work.

Here is my context class

```
public class TrackerContext : DbContext
{
    public TrackerContext() : base() {}
    public DbSet<Toll> Tolls { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TollRecord> TollRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }
}
```

No connection strings. Can I force it in somehow??

Comment: I guess, you should delete debug folder and rebuild the project.

Comment: Sometimes Entity Framework has his owned connection string in the context. Check EF uses your web.config file and not a variable in his constructor.

Comment: If you install EF through NuGet your default connectionstring should get added automatically to the config file. Can you connect to `mysite.database.windows.net` in visual studio server explorer?

Comment: Debug and rebuild did not work. Yeah, I can connect to it in the explorer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your constructor to this:

```
 public TrackerContext() : base("Name=DefaultConnection") {}
```

Comment: This is saying to the underlying dbcontext where abouts to get the connection string from. The point of this is so that you can have multiple connection strings to different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Locol Connection string didnt show up on SQL Server Object Explorer...

**How I solved it was:**

Click on View tab,
Select SQL Server Object Explorer,
Right click on SQL Server and refresh.

It showed up right away.